# Flattest possible surface?

Tags: material-science

a) What is the flattest surface possible of any material? 
b) What is the flattest surface material available to humans at the present time?

Comment: Define flattest. What size are you wanting? 1 mm$^2$, 1m$^2$, etc?

Comment: May I suggest that using the imperative mode at people who you are asking for a favor is neither polite nor a good strategy for getting thoughtful answers.

Comment: How about reversing the 5 downvotes while you're at it? (_mod note: edited_)

Comment: Moderator tools cannot track specific votes nor reverse them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Various single crystals can be cleaved to an atomically flat surface. There's a high temperature superconductor that is strongly planar, but with weak interplanar bonds that can be made atomically flat by simply sticking a sticky tape on the surface and ripping it away

Comment: Name of that high temperature superconductor if you remember it?

Comment: Bissco I think. It's been a while

Comment: Answering the question, not downvoting, tapdancing about semantics etc? Good for you!